# Define relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How do I define the relationships here with EF Core?

I have an `Employee` table which has multiple `Jobs`

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<HourlyRate> DefaultRate { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateHired { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Job` class has an `Employee` object to navigate back to the employee and the `Job` has multiple Directors which are also Employees

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public JobType Type { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Directors { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Deduction { get; set; }
    public int? DeductionPercent { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasMany(employee => employee.Jobs)
                .WithOne(i => i.Employee);
}
```

Initially the Job only had a single Director and everything was good but the requirement has changed to have multiple directors and ef removed the Director column from the Job table and added a `JobId` column to the Employee table but the problem is that if i add that director to a second job by `job.Directors.Add(director)` EF overrides the job id of the of the director and the director is being removed from the previous job

I am using EF Core 2.2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key What don't you understand from this?

Comment: I can't figure out how to define the relationship of the directors column to have multiple directors

Comment: EF adds a foreign key to the job table but it is being overwritten when i add the same director to another job

Comment: So your question is about migrations, not relations?

Comment: You should show the code that "can't add the same director to more then 1 Job".

Comment: @GertArnold I can add more then one director to a job in the code above but when i add that director to a second job it overrides the job id of the of the director

Comment: "The code above" does nothing. Show the code that carries out what you describe.

Comment: I ended up upgrading to EF Core 5 which has built in support for many to many

Answer (score 0):

if a Job has only 1 Employee but multiple Directors (also Employee)

add `public int EmployeeId {get; set;}` to your Job class and add this

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Job>()
.HasMany(p => p.Directors)
.WithMany(p => p.Jobs));
```

also, change List<> to ICollection<>

Answer (score 0):

You should tell EF through fluent API that there's a 1-to-many relationship from Employee to Job. Otherwise, EF may get confused.

The many-to-many relationship needs a junction table and matching entity in the model which you'll also need to configure through fluent API. You'll define two 1-to-many relationships from `Employee` and `Job` to that new entity. EF core does not directly support such relationships before 5.0.

If you are targeting SQL, then you need to mark at least one of the relationships as `OnDelete(CascadeBehavior.NoAction)`. Otherwise, your model will generate invalid table defintions which will raise errors at creation time.

**Update:**

The junction table would be defined something like this.

```
public class Employee
{
    // ... other stuff
    public List<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    // ... other stuff
    public List<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJobs { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeJob
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

// goes in DbContext

modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeJob>.HasKey(x => new { x.EmployeeId, x.JobId });
```

Comment: There is 2 things here. 1. 1 employee has multiple jobs 2. 1 job has multiple directors. A director is an employee but i don't care about the job from the directors perspective only from the employee; meaning i need to know in the employee what his jobs are and in the job who the directors are but i don't care from the directors side which jobs he oversees

Comment: EF doesn't work like that. If you don't define a navigation property, it will synthesize one and add that as a shadow property at runtime with some weird name. You'll need to define a junction table and entity to handle the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: The difference between Jobs and directors are that each job can only belong to 1 employee but each director can oversee multiple jobs

Comment: How do i add a new Job to an employee or a new director to a Job?

Comment: Say you have `director1` and `job` who are related to each other, you do a `context.EmployeeJobs.Add(new EmployeeJob { Director = director1, Job = job1 });` and save that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code. Since your employee can have one or many jobs I added the table EmployeeJob and many-to-many relations. I think you just need to add IsDirector flag to Employee or maybe better something like an EmployeeType:

```
public class Employee

    {
        public Employee()
    {
        EmployeeJobs = new HashSet<EmployeeJob>();
    }
    [Key]
   
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateHired { get; set; }
    
    
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(EmployeeJob.Employee))]
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJobs { get; set; }
}


public class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        EmployeeJobs = new HashSet<EmployeeJob>();
    }
    [Required]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool Deduction { get; set; }
    public int? DeductionPercent { get; set; }
    
    [InverseProperty(nameof(EmployeeJob.Job))]
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJobs { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeJob
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(EmployeeId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(EmployeeJob.Employee.EmployeeJobs))]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int JobId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(JobId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(EmployeeJob.Employee.EmployeeJobs))]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDbContext()
    {
    }

    public EmployeeDbContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeJob> EmployeeJobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=Employee;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeJob>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Employee)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeJobs)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmployeeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EmployeeJob_Employee");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Job)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeJobs)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.JobId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EmployeeJob_Job");
        });

    }
```